# How can I test for null arguments in the constructor of abstract class using rhino mocks?

Tags: .net, constructor, nunit, rhino-mocks, arguments

I have a class like so:

```
public abstract class ClassA<T>
{
    protected ClassA(IInterface interface)
    {
    if (interface== null)
            {
            throw new ArgumentNullException ("interface");
            }
    }
}
```

I want to write a test which verifies that if I pass null in the exception is thrown:

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException (typeof (ArgumentNullException))]
public TestMethod()
{
    ClassA classa = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ClassA<String>> (null);
}
```

but the test keeps failing with an exception rather than the exception being expected.  I also tried wrapping the call in a try catch block, but same issue.  I tried GenerateStub and PartialMock.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently run into this issue myself, unfortunately I haven't been able to find any way to tell Rhino not to wrap the exception itself. Thus far, the best I've been able to come up with would be as follows:

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public void TestMethod()
{
    try
    {
        ClassA classa = _mocks.CreateMock<ClassA>(null);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (e.InnerException != null)
        {
            throw e.InnerException;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        _mocks.ReplayAll();
    }
}
```